# Azure Database for PostgreSQL Basic Plan and Debugging

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-database-postgresql

We are using Azure Database for PostgreSQL Basic Plan (vCore 2) for development environment.

When we try to debug our application from Visual Studio (EF PostgreSQL), we often get "Unknown message code: 21 (also 2 and 3)" errors.

Is it limitation of basic plan or another problem?

We were using "General Purpose" Plan before and we were not dealing with these problems. We had to change our plan because of high pricing.

Comment: Can you please provide more error messages?

Comment: It's all about azure postgresql limitations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-limits